# How do I make my bootstrap buttons look the way I want but still function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got these bootstrap 3.x buttons in my navbar and I like the way they look when I do this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary"  asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</button></li>
            <li><button class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary"  asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</button></li>
        </ul>
```

but the problem is they don't take me to the path I need like these do:

**ugly but functional**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I've tried wrapping both in a form, which kinda works. It looks as intended, but it submits the page once it opens (effectively submitting an empty form on my webpage)

EDIT: I've just run around in .css and made it look the way I need as an anchor. thanks for the effort though gentleman.

Comment: Seems to be a limition of the ASP you're using, it's hasn't got much to do with Twitter-bootstrap. You could, of course, change the style of the anchors to look like the buttons in bootstrap.

Comment: In javascript, use addEventListener("click", () => {your code to redirect;}); to the button elements.

Answer (score 0):

`asp-area`, `asp-controller` and `asp-action` are anchor tag helpers which will not yield same output in button tag because they are specifically meant for a tag. For your buttons to work in same manner you need to add something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary" onclick = "window.open('Account/Register')">Register</button></li>
            <li><button class="btn btn-sm navbar-link navbar-btn btn-primary" onclick="window.open('Account/Login')">Log in</button></li>
        </ul>
```

or as suggested by @Jeff Matthews you can add javascript,

`addEventListener("click", () => {your code to redirect;});`

to the button elements.[EventListner MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: this works to a point, if the user wants to click the "Log In" button or "Register" button after they've already pressed one, it appends 'Account/Login' on the end of the url, creating an invalid url of ".../Account/Account/Login". Looks like the only way I can do this is in Javascript, would you agree?